# How to choose a Key and Offset for a Kafka Producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm following [here](https://github.com/amient/hello-kafka-streams).While following the code. I came up with two Questions

1. Is the Key and offset were the same?

According to Google,

> **Offset:** A Kafka topic receives messages across a distributed set of
>   partitions where they are stored. Each partition maintains the
>   messages it has received in a sequential order where they are
>   identified by an offset, also known as a position.

*Seems both are very similar for me. Since offset maintain a unique message in the partition: Producers send records to a partition based on the record’s key*

2. What is the best way to choose the Key/Offset for a producer?

For an instance the example which I provided above, they have chosen the timestamp as the Key and offset.
Is this the always the best recommendation?

```
 class IRCMessageListener extends IRCEventAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onPrivmsg(String channel, IRCUser u, String msg) {
        IRCMessage event = new IRCMessage(channel, u, msg);
        //FIXME kafka round robin default partitioner seems to always publish to partition 0 only (?)
        long ts = event.getInt64("timestamp");
        Map<String, ?> srcOffset = Collections.singletonMap(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, ts);
        Map<String, ?> srcPartition = Collections.singletonMap(CHANNEL_FIELD, channel);
        SourceRecord record = new SourceRecord(srcPartition, srcOffset, topic, KEY_SCHEMA, ts, IRCMessage.SCHEMA, event);
        queue.offer(record);
    }
```

Because I'm actually trying to create a custom Kafka connector to get the data from 3rd Party WebSocket API. The API sends real-time data stream messages for a given Key value. So I thought of using that Key for my PartitionKey as well as Offset. But need to make sure I'm right about my thought.

Comment: You're confusing the source offset with the internal Kafka offset, which has no relation to a Kafka message key. See JavaDoc. *The `sourcePartition` represents a single input `sourcePartition` that the record came from (e.g. a filename, table name, or topic-partition). The `sourceOffset` represents a position in that `sourcePartition` which can be used to resume consumption of data.* - So, unless you can resume from a timestamp in a websocket, then you don't really need a source offset as part of that record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key is an optional metadata, that can be sent with a Kafka message, and by default, it is used to route message to a specific partition. E.g. if you're sending a message *m* with key as *k*, to a topic *mytopic* that has *p* partitions, then *m* goes to the partition Hash(*k*) % *p* in *mytopic*. It has no connection to the offset of a partition whatsoever. Offsets are used by consumers to keep track of the position of last read message in a partition. In your case, if the timestamp is fairly randomly distributed, then it's fine, else you might be causing partition imbalance while using it as key.

Comment: What if one selects the wrong Key and what will be the result if the partition imbalance occurs?

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you meant by selecting the *wrong key*. In case you used the key which you weren't supposed to use, that particular message *might* go to a different partition, that's all. And for partition imbalance, I meant that some of the partitions would get many more messages that the rest.  So the consumers consuming from those partitions would be busy, while others would be mostly idle.

Answer (score 0):

These are some basic differences :

Offset : maintained by kafka to keep a track of the records consumed to avoid loss of records and duplicate records while consuming.

Key : it is specific to input events,if it is not available then by default it is mentioned as null,this is useful while writing records to HDFS with default partition-er using kafka connect.every message can have a single key or many messages can have similar key.