# Registering Schema ID with Topic using confluent_kafka for python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

The only answer I have gotten so far, is that you have to give the schema and the topic the same name, and then this should link them together. But after registering a schema with name `test_topic` like:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test_topic",
  "namespace": "com.test",
  "doc": "My test schema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

and running the following command, it inserts without a problem.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data '{"records":[{"value":{"name": "My first name"}}]}' "http://localhost/topics/test_topic"
```

But when I run the following command as well it inserts without giving any error (note,I changed the property name)

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data '{"records":[{"value":{"test": "My first name"}}]}' "http://localhost/topics/test_topic"
```

I would have suspected an error message saying that my data does not match the schema for this topic...

My schema ID is 10, so I know it is working and registered, but not very useful at the moment.

Python Code:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import socket
import json
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'client.id': socket.gethostname()}
producer = Producer(conf)

def acked(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print(f'Failed to deliver message: {str(msg)}, {str(err)}')
    else:
        print(f'Message produced: {str(msg)}')

    producer.produce("test_topic", key="key", value=json.dumps({"test": name}).encode('ascii') , callback=acked)

producer.poll(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you have to give the schema and the topic the same name, and then this should link them together

That's not quite how the Schema Registry works.

Each kafka record has a key and a value.

The Registry has subjects, which are not strictly mapped to topics.

However, the Kafka clients (de)serializer implementation will use both `topic-key` and `topic-value` subject names to register/extract schemas from the registry.

Clients cannot tell the registry what ID to put the schema at. That logic is calculated server side

---

I'm not sure I understand what your post has to do with the REST Proxy, but you're posting plain JSON and not telling it that the data should be Avro (you're using the incorrect header)

> If Avro is used, the content type will be `application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json`

Comment: Hi, I took a look at the avro schema example on the github page here: `https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python`. Everything works now as I thought it would, but do I have to include the value and key schematics every time I produce a message, even though I can see the schematics registered in kafka_schematics? What id I have two producers, then I would have to update any change in the schematics in two places?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what `kafka_schematics` means. But yes, producers always require a schema to be locally available. And you're not required to use Avro for both key and value

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what a key-value pair does, but according to this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245962/how-to-choose-a-key-and-offset-for-a-kafka-producer` a key basically just tells kafka in what partition the record has to go to. Does this mean that the key does not actually have anything to do with the schema? Do you have any resource that explains the key-value concept better? I already went through all the official documentation :/

Comment: The key determines the partition, yes. It's optional in any Kafka producer. And it has its own Schema (in your code it's just a string). In terms of the REST Proxy, you would have to send both key and value together in one request